# Python slicing replace : with a variable

Tags: python, numpy

I want to replace the column slicing of a Numpy Array by a variable. e.g.

```
a = np.zeros((3, 3))
slic = 3
a[:, slic]
```

So how do I represent : case where:

```
a[:, slic] == a[:, :]
```

so what should `slic =` ?

Many thanks

J

Comment: `slice(None)`  This a standard python obhect class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the colon notation inside brackets generates an internal `slice(start, end, step)` object. Your specific `slic` should therefore be set to `slice(None)`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) for details.

Note that numpy slices can generally be an integer, a slice object, an Ellipsis, a newaxis, or a tuple of the above. You could therefore also assign `slic` to the tuple `(slice(None), slice(None))` and pass that in instead. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for numpy details.